# how to transfer a geotif with WGS84 to a mercator array for ploting it with matplotlib.basemap

Tags: python, wgs84, matplotlib, coordinate-system, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot data from a sensor raster file (tif) to a map using basemap.
I have a geotif with 'WGS 84'

```
>>> gtif = gdal.Open("example.tif")
>>> print gtif.GetProjectionRef()
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
```

My map is using 'merc'

```
>>> m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=-26, urcrnrlat=48, llcrnrlon=-28, urcrnrlon=42, lat_ts=20, resolution='c')
```

How can I convert the tif in the merc projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gdal.

Have a look at [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to convert to from tif to another format (although the tif is likely the best option).

Then use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject to mercator.

Gdal is written in python so you should be able to incorporate it straight into your workflow.